# Print Barcode using zpl prints blank labels

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I tried to print barcode using `zpl`. But sometimes it prints blank pages.
My code is:

```
^XA
^MMT
^PW624
^LL0192
^LS0
^FO10,20^AP,30,30^FDCompany^FS
^FO10,57^AD^FDItem name^FS
^BY3,1,35^FT10,130^BCN,50,N,N,N,A
^FD201000^FS
^FO10,133^AQ^FD201000^FS
^FO10,160^AQ^FDRs. 650.00^FS
^FO160,164^AP^FDbrand^FS

^FO328,20^AP,30,30^FDCompany^FS
^FO328,57^AD^FItem name^FS
^BY3,1,35^FT328,130^BCN,50,N,N,N,A
^FD001000^FS
^FO328,133^AQ^FD001000^FS
^FO328,160^AQ^FDRs. 650.00^FS
^FO478,164^AP^FDbrand^FS
^PQ3,1,1,Y^XZ
```

My printer is a `TSP TTP-244 Pro` and Label Size is 24mm x 37mm. Double column label.

Comment: what does this got to do with PHP?

Comment: Not in php I just tried to print like this  https://jsfiddle.net/8jtL87n7/

Comment: Improved formatting and cleaned up tags.